# How to search for a single object in Firebase, and then do something with it without using forEach?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I want to search for a user, say by email, and then do some database operations which use the user's id, and then do some things that rely on it. I couldn't find a way to do this without using forEach which I'm not sure how to use with the promises here.

```
function addStuff(email) {
  return admin.firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==', email).get().then((users) => {
     if (users.size !== 1) {
       throw Error("Found "+users.size+" matching users for "+email);
     }
     // Somehow get the id of the first (and only) user in the snapshot without forEach, then:
     new_data = {
       user_id: userID,
       other_data: XXX
     }
     return admin.firestore().collection("YYY").add(new_data);
   }).then(()=>{
     // Do some other things after database is updated
   }).catch(er=>{
     console.log("Error: "+er);
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#docs) property of the [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), which returns "an array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`" and use the first element of this array.

```
function addStuff(email) {
  return admin.firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==', email).get()
   .then((users) => {
     if (users.size !== 1) {
       throw Error("Found "+users.size+" matching users for "+email);
     }
     const new_data = users.docs[0].data();

     return admin.firestore().collection("YYY").add(new_data);
   }).then(()=>{
     // Do some other things after database is updated
   }).catch(er=>{
     console.log("Error: "+er);
   })
}
```